# How to make dropdown box content push down the div after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now the dropdown box content just overlaps the div underneath it. I'd like to have it push down the content instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/fLmsg3aj/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  function t(t) {
    e(t).bind("click", function(t) {
      t.preventDefault();
      e(this).parent().fadeOut()
    })
  }
  e(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    var t = e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").is(":hidden");
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
    if (t) {
      e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").toggle().parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active")
    }
  });
  e(document).bind("click", function(t) {
    var n = e(t.target);
    if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")) e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
  });
  e(document).bind("click", function(t) {
    var n = e(t.target);
    if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")) e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
  })
});
```

Comment: if i got your point .. in css remove position:absolute; and the div after it make  clear:both;  is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/fLmsg3aj/1/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Ah I see. Is there a way to add a css animation to it? Like to have the pushed div move over 1sec? Should I use `transition`?

Comment: more of options .. transition in css  or in jquery slideToggle() , fadeToggle() , addClass() ; choose from it  so instead of show(); you can use slideDown(); and slideUp() instead of hide() .. take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/fLmsg3aj/2/